# How can I prevent Windows 10 from launching any app when clicking on a email link?

Tags: windows, windows-10, email

Whenever I click on anything that has a @ symbol in browser, Word, Excel, or anywhere else, Windows launches Mail app. I do not want it to launch anything. I uninstalled the Mail app, so now Windows launches a table asking me which program to use to open that link. I do not want to use any program, I just want Windows to ignore me clicking on email addresses. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have set Word to automatically detect and convert text to hyperlinks,
so it indeed converted text containing `@` to hyper-links.

To undo this option:

- Enter the menu *File > Options > Proofing*,
- Click *AutoCorrect Options...*
- In the dialog, position to the *AutoFormat* tab
- Untick "Internet and network paths with hyperlinks"
- Click OK.
- To convert to simple text all existing hyperlinks, press
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
  to select the entire document and then press
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

Take a backup of the document before starting on the above.

---

Excel is a particularly difficult case, because it follows a hyperlink
with a simple click, unlike Word that only does it for
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>.
This makes it quite frustrating to edit a cell that contains a hyperlink.

You will find various methods for editing such fields and avoiding
activating the hyperlink in the post
[How to stop Excel following hyperlinks when I click on them?](https://superuser.com/questions/595383/how-to-stop-excel-following-hyperlinks-when-i-click-on-them)

Comment: This isn't just on Word, but on dozens of other applications. And in most cases, I do need them as hyperlinks. I just don't need them to be opened on this particular PC.

Comment: Each application may have its options - this isn't a Windows settings. Office apps have it in *Options > Proofing*, but you need to do them one by one. A global possibility is that you might possibly have installed a utility that does it, which you can test by booting into Safe mode to disable it.

Comment: In any case, you need Ctrl+Click to follow a link, just a click shouldn't be enough.

Comment: Sir, I believe you misunderstand. Each application has options to turn the words with "@" symbol into hyperlinks or not, but clicking on such links is a Windows "mailto" protocol, which I want to disable. This behavior isn't application-dependent.

Comment: This will only be automatic in the browser. A simple click shouldn't be enough in desktop apps.

Comment: Well, but it is. In Excel, for example, a simple click is enough to launch Mail app.

Comment: Verified: Does not happen in Word, but does happen in Excel. I added in my answer a link to a useful post, but this requires some discipline when working in Excel.

Comment: I checked out that link, but what these people are suggesting are workarounds, not a solution. I need a solution. Keep the hyperlinks, but make the program ignore them when clicked. Just like it's handled in Word.

Comment: So would many other people, but Microsoft doesn't listen. Microsoft itself [suggests](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/work-with-hyperlinks-in-excel-7fc80d8d-68f9-482f-ab01-584c44d72b3e) only the methods of the right-click or the long click.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has to make an app that handles the `mailto` protocol. The app must not do anything (like silently open and close itself).

You can test the reasoning in PowerShell:

```
(Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\mailto\Us
erChoice' -Name ProgId).ProgID
```

When it asks for a value, leave it blank.

Now Windows will either reset it on its own or ask you which app you want.

More convincingly, if you go into `regedit` and delete the `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\mailto\UserChoice` node, Windows will eventually notice its gone and recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

I can only imagine that you are clicking on the @ to copy some text around that.  If so, I basically start the mouse select from before the link and slide over the "@" area, then copy, then edit that elsewhere as I use it.  Hopefully there is at least a space between email addresses where you can start your select.

If this isn't the use case, please clarify.

Comment: That is sometimes the case, but most of the times, it isn't. I just need my PC to ignore these links altogether. What you suggested is sometimes very inconvenient. For example, I need to double-click a word that as the "@" symbol in it, rather than doing the slide selection.

Comment: You don’t indicate what application these links appear in, however, it’s the application that’s making them into links that Windows is treating as a mailto link.

Comment: This isn't just on Word, but on dozens of other applications. And in most cases, I do need them as hyperlinks. I just don't need them to be opened on this particular PC.

Comment: So disable the functionality within the application on that PC?

Comment: Most applications do not have an option to disable it... But it still depend on Windows as to which mail application to launch - and I want to tell Windows to ignore this request when it receives it from any application.